# Inequality for singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I stumbled on the following inequality for singular values (stated without proof), and would like to understand it better:

Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n$ real matrices. Denoting by $\mu_i(C)$ the $i$-th singular value of a matrix $C$ and $by$ $\|\cdot\|$  the operator norm we have for $i=1,\dots,n$

$\mu_i(AB)  \ \leq \|A\| \ \mu_i(B)$

and

$\mu_i(AB)  \ \leq \|B\| \ \mu_i(A)$

Why is this true? Standard references? Is this inequality a specific property of singular values or does it work also for eigenvalues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The singular values of $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^T A$ (or equivalently of $A A^T$).  Thus the singular values of $AB$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $B^T A^T A B$ or $A B B^T A^T$.  Now for any vector $v$, $v^T A^T A v  
= \|A v\|^2 \le \|A\|^2 v^T v$.  Apply that to $v = B w$ and you get
$w^T B^T A^T A B w \le \|A\|^2 w^T B^T B w$.  By the Min-Max Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem it follows that $\mu_i(AB) \le \|A\| \mu_i(B)$.  Similarly, using $A B B^T A^T$ instead of $B^T A^T A B$ you get $\mu_i(AB) \le \|B\| \mu_i(A)$.

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer. As far as I understand the same reasoning doesn't work if $A,B$ are symmetric and if the $\mu_i$'s denote eigenvalues instead of singular values. Am I wrong? Do in that case the inequalities not hold?

Comment: Why $A^T A$ and $A A^T$ have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: ok, I got it: if $u$ is an eigenvector of $A^TA$ then $Au$ is an eigenvector of $AA^T$ with same eigenvalue, and viceversa.

Comment: @Filippo: if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, $AB$ is generally not symmetric, and its eigenvalues may not even be real.

Comment: For example, try $A = \pmatrix{2 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$, $B = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 0\cr}$.  Their product has eigenvalues $\pm i$.

Comment: I see. Thanks! To be more precise in my comment above: $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ have the same NON-ZERO eigenvalues.

Comment: In general yes.  For square matrices, there are the same number of $0$ eigenvalues as well.

Comment: oh yes, of course! I was thinking today on the generalization to rectangular matrices of the inequalities, which also should be true following your reasoning (if I didn't make a mistake): I just used what I wrote in my last comment, and treated separatedly the zero singular values..

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for your thorough and lucid answer, Robert. I used it for a proof in a research project, will definitely acknowledge you in the "Acknowledgement" once it got published. Thanks again!