# Holders inequality for Hilbert Schmidt operators which are also trace class

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, holder-inequality

Does Hilbert-Schmidt operators which are also trace class, satisfy Holders inequality? That is, we have two Hilbert Schmidt operators $A$ and $B$. Is the following true?
$$\langle A, B \rangle \leq \lVert A \rVert_p \lVert B \rVert_q $$

such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$ Specifically, is it true for $p=1, q=\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

*(I'll assume you are talking about the Schatten norms)*

Yes, it's true. It follows from the fact that you can express the trace-norms in terms of singular values.

First, since [$\sigma_n(B^*A)\leq \|B\|\,\sigma_n(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183744/inequality-for-singular-values),
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}(B^*A)
&=\sum_n\sigma_n(B^*A)\leq\|B\|\,\sum_n\sigma_n(A)=\|A\|_1\,\|B\|.
\end{align}

Now, 
\begin{align}
|\operatorname{Tr}(B^*A)|
&\leq \|I\|\,\|B^*A\|_1=\|B^*A\|_1=\sum_n\sigma_n(B^*A)\\ \ \\
&\leq \sum_n\sigma_n(A)\sigma_n(B)
\leq \left(\sum_n\sigma_n(A)^p\right)^{1/p}\left(\sum_n\sigma_n(B)^q\right)^{1/q}\\ \ \\
&=\|A\|_p\,\|B\|_q.
\end{align}
The last inequality above is the usual Hölder; the singular value inequality appears as Corollary 4.1 in Gohberg-Krein's Introduction to the Theory of Linear Nonselfadjoint Operators