# $\|\tau\|=trace(|B|)$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ the matrix space, $\tau:M_n(\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$
\tau(A)=trace(AB)
$$
We consider $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with norm $\|A\|^2=\sup\{|\lambda|\in\mathbb{C}:\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $A^*A\}$ (in other words, a norm of $C^*$-algebra).

We need resolve two problems:

1. $\|\tau\|=trace(|B|)$; (where $|B|=\sqrt{B^*B}$)
2. $\tau$ is positive iff $B$ is positive. (where $\tau$ is positive if $\tau(A^*A)\geqslant0$ for all $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $B$ is positive if $B=C^*C$ for any $B\in M_n(\mathbb{C}$).

I was studying by Murphy's book of Operator Algebras, but I didn't found a way to solve this problem. I also did a counts, but it was long and useless. If there is any idea to start...

--- EDIT ---

I first wanna to thank Martin Argerami for awnser, the part 2. to me it's ok, but part 1. I know a awnser that convinced me:

Define $\widetilde{\tau}$ by $\widetilde{\tau}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(A|B|)$. Consider the polar form of $B$ by $B=U|B|$, where $U$ is a isometry (not only partial, since is a matrix $n\times n$). Hence,
\begin{align*}
    |\tau(A)|
    =|\operatorname{tr}(AB)|
    =|\operatorname{tr}(AU|B|)|
    =|\widetilde{\tau}(AU)|
    \leqslant\|\widetilde{\tau}\|\|AU\|
    \leqslant\|\widetilde{\tau}\|\|A\|\|U\|
    \leqslant\|\widetilde{\tau}\|\|A\|.
\end{align*}
Let the sup of matrices of norm $\leqslant1$, we get
\begin{align*}
    \|\tau\|\leqslant\|\widetilde{\tau}\|.
\end{align*}
But, by (ii), we know that $\widetilde{\tau}$ é positive, since $|B|$ is positive. Also, we have that $\|\widetilde{\tau}\|=\widetilde{\tau}(I)$, since $\widetilde{\tau}$ is positive and $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is unital. Hence,
\begin{align*}
    \|\tau\|\leqslant\|\widetilde{\tau}\|=\widetilde{\tau}(I)=\operatorname{tr}(I|B|)=\operatorname{tr}(|B|).
\end{align*}
By other hand, $U^*$ is a matrix of norm $\leqslant1$ such that
\begin{align*}
    \tau(U^*)=\operatorname{tr}(U^*B)=\operatorname{tr}(|B|).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\|\tau\|=\tau(U^*)=\operatorname{tr}(|B|)$.

Answer (score 2):

You have, using [Hölder's Inequality for the trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2735965/22857)
$$
|\tau(A)|=|\operatorname{tr}(AB)|\leq\|A\|\,\operatorname{tr}(|B|). 
$$
So $\|\tau\|\leq\operatorname{tr}(|B|)$. If write $B=V|B|$ the polar decomposition, then you have $|B|=V^*B$. As $V$ is a partial isometry $\|V\|=1$, and so
$$
\tau(V^*)=\operatorname{tr}(V^*B)=\operatorname{tr}(|B|). 
$$
Hence $\|\tau\|=\tau(|B|)$.

If $B=C^*C$, and $A=D^*D$, then
$$
\tau(A)=\operatorname{tr}(D^*DC^*C)=\operatorname{tr}(CD^*DC^*)=\operatorname{tr}((DC^*)^*DC^*)\geq0. 
$$
Conversely, if $\tau(A)\geq0$ for all $A$ positive, fix any unit vector $x\in\mathbb C^n$. Let $P$ be the rank-one projection onto the span of $x$. Then
$$
\langle Bx,x\rangle=x^*Bx=\operatorname{tr}(PBP)=\operatorname{tr}(BP)=\tau(P)\geq0.
$$
Then $B$ is selfadjoint and  $B$  positive.

Comment: You seem to use $\tau$ and $\operatorname{tr}$ interchangeably throughout the proof. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: Indeed, what a mess! Edited, please let me know if you still see mistakes.

Comment: The second part is very nice, but I didn't understand what you did at first. I haven't see polar decomposition. And I don't catch "$|\operatorname{tr}(AB)|\leq\|A\|\,\operatorname{tr}(|B|)$"...

Comment: The inequality, I linked to a proof; it is also Theorem 2.4.16 in Murphy. The polar decomposition is Theorem 2.3.4 in Murphy.